# Looking for a novel from the late 80s/early 90s about punks on hover skates

Tags: story-identification, novel

Back in 92-93 I read a novel involving some young punks who rode around on hover skates (or possibly hover boards).  Don't really recall much else about it except the author included a listening list in the back which included Joy Division's *Closer*.

Don't suppose this vague memory is enough for someone to recognize this book, but worth a chance.

Comment: There has to be something else you remember. Anything form [this post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) maybe?

Comment: Was definitely in mass market at the time.  Pretty sure the main character was an early teen girl; cover may have been of her skating down some stairs, possibly being pursued?